# Where are login options stored?

Tags: terminal, settings, login

How can I read Login options from terminal (Automatic login, Display login windows as, Network Account Server etc.)?

Comment: All in various plists in ~/Library/Preferences or readable via defaults. To get a better answer you need to be more explicit what exactly do you need and want to do

Comment: In System Preferences->Users & Groups->Login Options are settings, that I need to extract and save.

Comment: As Mark already pointed out these settings are stored in various files. To make it easier to find a good answer, can you please amend the question to specifically list the options you are looking for? Adding an annotated screenshot of the Login Options screen might be useful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of these settings are stored in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist`. The "Show fast user switching menu" setting is stored at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist` (for each user account on the system).

The Network Account Server settings are stored in your Directory Services database. You can utilize the `dscl` command to look at various settings dealing with your Network Account Server. I recommend using `man dscl` to look at the details of this function, but as an example I can use the following command to see the Active Directory domain I'm bound to at work:

`dscl localhost -ls /Active\ Directory`

For Open Directory you would use:

`dscl localhost -ls /LDAPv3`

**Additional Note from OP**: `.plist` files are coded in binary. To read them in Terminal you will want to make a copy of the file that you can tinker with, and convert that copy into XML format. Use the `cp` command to create your copy and `plutil -convert xm11 examplefile.plist` to convert to readable XML.

Comment: THX a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for. I just add, that `plists` are binary, to convert them to xml use `plutil -convert xml1 some_file.plist`. Before that, copy them elsewhere to don't mess up config. Add this to the answer if you can.